# How to avoid two selections in UICollectionview at a time

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have collectionview on rootviewcontroller. If i click on collectionview cell it will navigate to detail View.

But if the user clicks on 2 cells at a time with his 2 fingers. It pushes two views at a time. so, How to avoid it.

The user is expected to push only one detail ViewController, even though he tries to click on two cells at a time with his 2 fingers.

Comment: [UICollectionView setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
Try this may be it solves your problem

Comment: Thanks, It is working.

Comment: Yes, [Collectionview setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO] and [CollectionViewCell setExclusiveTouch:YES];

Comment: @BikshapathiKumbala Check only single one at a time and check which one is works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[UICollectionView setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
```